# JavaScript text manipulation

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript and I want to replace any text between @anytext@ with some text. I want to make it generic so I am thinking to make use of regular expression. How do I do it?

Example:replace('@hello@','Hi')

Comment: Changed everything from jQuery to JavaScript, as it has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: I need to make little manipulation in this.I need to retrieve the matched text and then replace the matched text.Something like this Replace("@anytext@",<a href=#>@anytext@</a>) My string can have @anytext@ any where in string multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/@[^@]+@/g, 'Hi')
```

This will remove any sequences of `@ … @` globally with `Hi`.

---

**Edit**    Some explanation:

- `/…/` is the [regular expression literal syntax in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
- `@[^@]+@` describes any sequence of a literal `@`, followed by one or more (`+` quantifier) characters that is not a `@` (negated charcater class `[^@]`), followed by a literal `@`
- the `g` flag in `/…/g` allows global matches; otherwise only the first match would be replaced

Comment: Works.Please provide some explanation.I didnt find any where so I can create my own Regular expressions.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex function of jquery to accomplish that...
So find the @'s with a regular expression and afterwards use the replace function with the text you want.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with jQuery, but just plain old javascript.

```
var regexp = new RegExp("@([^@]+)@");
text.replace(re, "replacement text");
```

But what do you mean by generic? How generic do you want to make it?

You can find more information about regular expressions on http://regexp.info including how to use in in Javascript